# MAVEN - Accessing parent directory

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Let's say I got something like C:\workspace\pkg\pom.xml and I want to access C:\workspace how could I do it? 
I've already tried doing something like ../${project.basedir} but had no success.

Comment: Simply based on the above `../${project.basedir}`...

Comment: really?! Have you even read what's written!? :|

Comment: Not sure if you meant ${project.basedir}/..

Comment: @NielsBechNielsen the result of that is (keeping the names of the question) C:\workspace\pkg/.. (or, if you use a backslash, C:\workspace\pkg\..)

Comment: @LeonGuerrero Which is pretty much as I read the question..

Comment: @NielsBechNielsen nope. I'm saying I want to go up one folder and that's not the solution... There's a difference between C:\workspace\pkg/.. and C:\workspace ;)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you are trying to read the content of other projects in the workspace, you are building something brittle because you can never know whether another project is there. And you can probably find a "maven-like" way to achieve what you want to achieve (whatever it is).

Comment: If you have a pom file and try to get a level higher for whatever reason you usually doing something wrong...I'm not sure what you are really trying to do cause you didn't wrote so...best would be making a simple example project maybe no working and describe what you like to achieve...based on that it's easier to help...